# Firestore query 'array_contains' pass in array

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am looking at Firebase, cloud firestore and I am not understanding how I would perform a query and pass in an array.

```
const friendIds = [1, 2, 3];

Firestone.collection('conversations')
      .where('members', 'array-contains', friendIds)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => console.log(querySnapshot))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible with a single query.  array-contains can only find a single item in the named array.

Your alternative is to perform three queries, one for each item in the `friendsId` array, then merge the results in your code.

Comment: is this still the case in 2023?

Answer (score 0):

> **Not sure if this is possible, but here's an example from the [Firebase Node.js Snippets](https://github.com/firebase/snippets-node/blob/d769695bd1159103e7c877849ccaccab3db37039/firestore/main/index.js#L681-L682) that can give you an idea:**

```
  let citiesRef = db.collection('cities');

  // [START array_contains_filter]
  let westCoastCities = citiesRef.where('regions', 'array-contains',
    'west_coast');

  // [END array_contains_filter]

  westCoastCities.get()
    .then(res => {
      console.log('West Coast get: ', res);
    });
```

**Reference [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership)**

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation regarding [query operators](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#query_operators):

> You can use the array-contains operator to filter based on array values.

As I can see in your code, your `friendIds` argument that is passed as the third parameter to the `where()` function is of type `array`. What you are actually doing, you are searching in the `members` property which is of type array for an array, which is actually **not** possible since I assume the `members` array in your database contains numbers.

An query like this:

```
Firestone.collection('conversations')
      .where('members', 'array-contains', 3)
      .get()
      .then(querySnapshot => console.log(querySnapshot))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Will work perfectly fine because we are searching within the `members` array for a number.

If you need to query for all those numbers, you should perform three separate queries and combine the result client side.